# How to compare value of new object in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare value of object in Javascript?

```
var newNum = new Number(10);
console.log(newNum); (It displays Number {})
var newPanelId = "panel" + newNum;
console.log("New Panel ID:" + newPanelId); (It displays panel10. Perfect)
```

But when i compare

```
if (newNum === 10)
{
  console.log("Print It");
}
```

It does not execute above if. Why?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9fot84gk/

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/9fot84gk/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9fot84gk/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used the condition `newNum === "10"`. The *triple* `=` means it checks the type as well, and as you've used quotes around `10` it is looking for a string, so it never evaluates to true.

Instead, do `newNum == 10` (or, as a *double* `=` only checks value, and *not* type, `newNum == "10"` will also work):

```js
var newNum = new Number(10);
console.log(newNum);
var newPanelId = "panel" + newNum;
console.log("New Panel ID:" + newPanelId);

if (newNum == 10) {
  console.log("Print It");
}
```

[updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9fot84gk/3/)

Answer (score 2):

The `new` keyword actually creates a number type object where the number 10 is not a number type object. The `===` operator checks whether the type and the value so your condition is false at every time. Adding a `+` prefix will make it a number so that you could compare.

Answer (score 1):

Because `new Number(10)` will return a new object of type [**`Number`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) which will never be equal to a [**primitive**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). If you want to compare `Number` object with actual integer or float number you need to convert it first, say with a shorthand `+` prefix: `+newNum === 10` or simply use non-strict comparison: `newNum == 10`.